# How to remove repeated items in an R chart legend?

Tags: r, database, dplyr, graphics, dataset

I'm working with `starwars` dataset (`dplyr` package), and I want to make a graph where the independent variable is the height of the characters, and the dependent variable is their body mass. Furthermore, I also want to discern species by colors:

```
library(dplyr)
starwars

par(mar = c(5.3, 4.3, 4.3, 8.3), xpd = TRUE)
plot(starwars$mass ~ starwars$height, ylim = c(0, 200),
col = as.factor(starwars$species), bty = "l")

legend("topright", inset = c(-0.2, 0), legend = as.factor(starwars$species),
cex = 0.50, col = as.factor(starwars$species),
ncol = 2, pch = 16)
```

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWKXL.jpg)

Note that some species are repeated in the legend. How to exclude these repetitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include only the `unique` values in `legend` :

```
plot(starwars$mass ~ starwars$height, ylim = c(0, 200),
     col = as.factor(starwars$species), bty = "l")
legend("topright", inset = c(-0.2, 0), 
       legend = as.factor(unique(starwars$species)),
       cex = 0.50, col = as.factor(unique(starwars$species)),
       ncol = 2, pch = 16)
```